# SumAsync EF Core float precision

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to sum values registred in database as float with EF Core

```
public async Task<double> ObtenirTotalStockParSiteAsync(long siteId)
            => await Queryable.Where(snapshot => snapshot.SiteId == siteId).SumAsync(snapshot => snapshot.Quantite).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The value registred in database is 40,005
[image]

But, the value returned with SumAsync is : 40.004999999999995

Can you help please to get 40,005

Quantite has the type float in my Sql Server Database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: If you need it to be exact you need use `decimal` instead of `float` or `double`.  And that would need to be the type in the DB as well.